# What games have complex rules for arrow removal?

Tags: game-recommendation, healing, damage, ranged-attack, simulation

**What tabletop RPGs have rules specifically for dealing with arrows that have been implanted into one's body?**

It is very common for RPG rules to keep arrows simple and merely have them do one-time damage, and then have them be "forgotten about" as they simply vanish or such.  However, certainly one of the powerful realistic advantages of arrows (and some other projectiles) is that they linger and intentionally stick in ways that are difficult and perhaps even further damaging to remove.  What RPGs exist that embrace this element of the weapon?

Comment: Are you looking for a game to play, or rules to borrow, or what?

Comment: Good question, this is something that tends to be glossed over a lot despite the fact that historically, a lot of arrow-related deaths were from the infections in the wounds.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton I am not asking for any particular reason at all.  It just came to mind, and I was curious.

Comment: The phrasing of your question will produce many "list" answers. (We don't like them.) While this question can be quite good, it always needs standing (a real problem to solve). Therefore, I will ask you to narrow the question from "list" to either best systems or a mechanic to borrow: in whatever way benefits your games in the real world the best.

Comment: Is there really going to be a list? Does such a game even exist? The question could perhaps be reworded as "What mechanics do roleplaying systems use for arrow removal?"

Comment: @Petr Unfortunately, the problem with that phrasing is that an answer can be created for, quite literally, every roleplaying system in existence. Thus, the question would have too many possible answers.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton I'm not really sure how to do this.  If you were willing to edit the question to whatever you think would make it appropriate, I'd be completely okay with whatever it becomes.

Comment: What system do you currently play in?

Comment: Yes, many "game-rec" list questions can be made into a good question by just asking for a good published mechanic that achieves goal X.  Of course, "just being curious" doesn't tend to render a decently scoped requirement of goal X...

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton I don't "currently" play anything.

Comment: In that case, I can see how you'd have a hard time rewriting the question to be more pointed. If you're really just wondering and want to see a selection of games though, even if you managed to rewrite it to have an answerable goal you wouldn't get very satisfying answers here due to the strictures of our format. This sounds like an excellent discussion topic for a forum such as RPG.net though, and you're much more likely to get a broad sampling of games in such a venue too.

Comment: Boo hiss to closing this question! @Emrakul As Petr mentions, there are not many games that have detailed arrow removal rules. The only one that comes to mind is GURPS, and even then you need to find the optional detailed rules for it.